# datetime.datetime.utcnow() randomly set 7 days back

Tags: python, tweepy, python-datetime

I have an issue I can't figure how to fix.

I have a python script that basically query twitter api with tweepy.

Everything works fine but randomly I got a 400 bad request error caused by a wrong parameter. The parameter in question is start_time, I use it to limit the search to the last 60 seconds (this script runs constantly and do a query every 5 seconds).

So the parameter is calculated like this:

```
datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=60)
```

As I said it works 99,9% of the time, but occasionally it jump one week back. So for instance if I have a look at the log, I can see that there is a query at 2022-04-25T23:29:40.000Z and the following with an error

400 Bad Request
Invalid 'start_time':'2022-04-18T23:31Z'. 'start_time' must be on or after 2022-04-18T23:31Z

As if the server randomly moved from 2022-04-25 back to 2022-04-18

What it makes everything hard to troubleshoot is that this script runs as a service. If I do a stop and start of the service, without touching at all the server date, everything works as expected.

I encountered this error maybe a couple of time in more than two months of 24h 7/7 service run.

What can I do to troubleshoot this error? It is random.

A quick fix could be to handle the exception, I do that with

```
except tweepy.errors.HTTPException as e:
            print(e)
            return('error')
```

But I don't know how to close and restart the service in this case.

Any help?

Comment: we need more of your code and runtime context. From this, it could be something like a virtual machine hosting the script having time drift when it suspends/resumes. or it could be that you have an error in your code. no way to tell without more info

Comment: you're right Ben. I miss some details. The script is running on a VPS on OVH. As I told you the issues has appeared only two times in more than two months, so it's unlikely related to suspend.